# Using isin to return values from two specific columns from two Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with identifiers for physical facilities.  I then have a list of facilities.  I would like to return only the locations used in both dataframes from my master list.  I am attempting to get the following to work, and it appears I have something in the syntax incorrect, or am not using isin properly.

```
print(filtered_locations[filtered_locations['id'].isin(filtered_departments.buildingid,filtered_stores.facilityid)])
```

I have tried a few variations of this - while there are many examples in the documents that specifically show how to scan two lists using dictionaries etc. I am having trouble sourcing the quickest/most direct way to return only values that are in the two specified columns in the other dataframes.

Comment: use a set such that `df[df['id'].isin(set(df2.columnA.values) & set(df3.columnB.values))]`

Comment: Thank you - This appears to be a very elegant solution, however, it appears to be returning an empty dataframe after I swap out the placeholders for df with my actual dataframe names.  Is there something I can check or watch out for?

Comment: Actually, I changed AND to OR since one of the frames in this case returned NAN, I'll have to test this further but it may work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for `pandas.Series.isin()` method.

It only accepts one parameter which is

> values : set or list-like

what you have given is tuple of two lists, so you need to merge your two lists in a single list-like or set, set is probably much better as it will not contain duplicated values.

**Code**

```
ids = set(filtered_departments.buildingid.tolist() +\
filtered_stores.facilityid.tolist())

my_locations = filtered_locations[filtered_locations['id'].isin(ids)]
```